# Не работает триггер на AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, триггер, триггеры-sql

Нужно создать триггер который при обновлении одной таблицы, обновляет и другую, то есть работает на AFTER INSERT.
Код:

```
create trigger `After_Insert_New`
after insert on `Vakansia`
for each row
begin
    update Kilkist set kilkist_vakansiy = (kilkist_vakansiy + 1);
end;
```

> Error:
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update Kilkist set kilkist_vakansiy = kilkist_vakansiy + 1      end' at line 7

Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: Триггер явно ошибочен. Логически. Ибо он должен обновить ВСЕ записи таблицы `Kilkist` при вводе любой записи в `Vakansia`. Где условия отбора?

Comment: то есть нужно добавить where или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger `After_Insert_New`
after insert on `Vakansia`
for each row
begin
    update Kilkist set kilkist_vakansiy = (kilkist_vakansiy + 1);
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Спасибо, триггер создался, но он не работает. Он не сумирует после insert в другой таблице.

Comment: Если таблицы `Vakansia` и `Kilkist` указаны верно, то должно суммировать. Или выдавать ошибку

Comment: *он не работает. Он не сумирует* Это разные вещи. Не работать он не может (иначе было бы сообщение об ошибке), а вот не обновляет он из-за отсутствия условия отбора и safe_update.

Comment: safe_update я отключил в найстройках mysql workbench, но все равно не работает

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, уже пофиксил.

Comment: Akina, при отсутствии условия будут просуммированы все поля `kilkist_vakansiy` А при режиме `safe_update` всплывет ошибка